# Class "sheet container" in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

(English is not my native language, PROMT translate)

Hello. I study the page [**Default.sublime-theme**](https://github.com/cj/sublime/blob/master/Theme%20-%20Default/Default.sublime-theme). There are lines:

```
{
"class": "sheet_container_control",
"layer0.tint": [64, 64, 64],
"layer0.opacity": 1.0
},
```

To what element the class `sheet_container_control` sets properties? Where I can see this element? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `sheet_container_control` is the setting for an empty window's background. See the [Soda theme](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/blob/master/Soda%20Dark%203.sublime-theme#L412-L420) for descriptions of the various controls.

Comment: I apologize, you couldn't provide a screenshot that I could understand where there is an element which values are set by the class 'sheet_container_control'? I don't see that somewhere there were changes. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных If you open a new window, but no file is yet open, the blank space where you would normally see the contents of open files is the `sheet_container_control`.

Comment: `File` → `New Window`. [I see it](https://i.gyazo.com/f4be8be6aac2befde1b57ad828b8bc4c.png). Forgive, I not really well speak English, it is possible therefore I don't understand you. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't understand that changes this class. After `"highlight_line": false` too is occurred nothing. Nevertheless, big to you thank you that spent the time for the answer to me.

Comment: @СашаЧерных glad to help. Если вы не возражаете, могли бы нажать на галочку, чтобы включить его зеленый? Это означает, что вы принимаете ответ. Спасибо! (from Google Translate, sorry for any errors!)

Comment: MattDMo, I understand that you are asking me to click on the green check mark. But the question isn't solved, [**I didn't see my eyes**](https://i.gyazo.com/f4be8be6aac2befde1b57ad828b8bc4c.png) that is set by a class `sheet_container_control`. Therefore I can't accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: MattDMo, you could show a screenshot where there would be an element which changes a class `sheet_container_control`?

Comment: @СашаЧерных as far as I have been able to tell, when other controls are specified, this one is "covered up" and not visible, but I don't know what those controls *are*. Careful Google searching has yielded nothing - there is no other documentation on this online that I can find. I've looked at a number of different themes that have it, and have used random values to try to highlight it, but nothing has appeared so far. I'm beginning to wonder if it's even active in ST3.