# Settings type «invisibles» and «shadow» in Sublime Text 3 .tmTheme file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have read the [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html) for the Color Schemes. I realized all settings except [`invisibles`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html#general) and [`shadow`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html#shadow) (+`shadowWidth`). I can translate from English, but I do not see anywhere where the elements, the color of which changes settings. Does anyone could show me the screenshots, where there are elements which change color? Thanks.

Comment: [shadow](http://imgur.com/a/YCkPK) - the red lines in these images. only visible when the text in the document is wider than the window. Will appear on the left and/or the right, depending whether the view can be scrolled to the left or the right.

Comment: I've logged an issue [here](https://github.com/guillermooo/sublime-undocs/issues/193) about the shadow and shadowWidth documentation. `invisibles` says it is ignored, so guessing changing it has no effect on the appearance of any elements in the editor.

Comment: **[1]** Sorry, [**I don't see red color line**](https://i.gyazo.com/569aca651481fcf6a6ce65076dc90a7f.png), **[2]** Why in that case created the `invisibles` setting?

Comment: 1: in my experience, you will only see the shadow if you have not got `shadowWidth` set in your tmTheme file. To make it red, I set `shadow` to `#FF0000` 2: I believe the tmTheme format is borrowed from a different text editor, to make it easier to use the same color scheme in different editors. So maybe it does something in other text editors, but not in ST.

Comment: @KeithHall, I switched to other color scheme, closed and opened the Sublime Text 3 program, closed and reopened the file where lines have to be shown, returned to my color scheme, and, at last, [**saw color lines**](https://i.gyazo.com/e38c6631b364591fd2ffdf85b254b57f.png) :) . For some reason at first changes weren't visible at once to me. But the element corresponding to a class `sheet_container` [**I don't see**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663238/class-sheet-container-in-sublime-text-3#comment60947765_36667410) :( . Thanks, designate the comment as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the unofficial documentation on color schemes, linked to in your question, we can see that `invisibles` is ignored, so changing it has no effect on the appearance of any elements in ST3.  The `tmTheme` format is borrowed from a different text editor, to make it easier to use the same color scheme in different editors. So maybe it does something in other text editors, but not in ST. EDIT: support for `invisibles` has been added to ST in build 3149 - https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1992.

The effect of the `shadow` setting can be seen below, it is the pink parts on the far sides:
[image: shadow]

It is only visible when the text in the document is wider than the window - it will appear on the left when the view can be scrolled to the left and it will appear on the right when the view can be scrolled to the right.

From my testing, including `shadowWidth` in the `tmTheme` file will cause the shadow to not appear.  I have logged an issue in the unofficial documentation [here](https://github.com/guillermooo/sublime-undocs/issues/193), maybe someone will update it with details of how to get this working.

---

Note:

When making changes to a`tmTheme` file, it is often necessary to close all open documents, and restart Sublime Text, before the change will become visible.